Error: Output format mp4 is not available
I'm using fluent-ffmpeg in my nextjs application, I'm trying to process the video and specified a format to stream on my s3 bucket but it keeps on failing. My terminal keeps on throwing "Error: Error: Output format mp4 is not available". I already verify my ffmpeg format "ffmpeg -format" and confirm that it supports encoding and decoding mp4 files. I've already tried solutions from other forums but it's not working for me.
createVideo: privateProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        fileId: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
      const user = await getUser();

      if (!user || !user.id || !user.email) {
        throw new TRPCError({ code: "UNAUTHORIZED" });
      }

      const dbUser = await db.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          id: user.id,
        },
      });

      if (!dbUser) {
        throw new TRPCError({
          code: "UNAUTHORIZED",
          message: "User not found in the database.",
        });
      }

      const putObjectCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
        Key: generateFileName(),
      });

      const s3 = new S3Client({
        region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION!,
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY!,
          secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY!,
        },
      });

      const singedURL = await getSignedUrl(s3, putObjectCommand, {
        expiresIn: 60,
      });

      const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");
      const passthroughStream = new PassThrough();

      ffmpeg({ source: "./template1.mp4" })
        .on("end", async () => {
          console.log("Job done");
          await uploadToS3(passthroughStream);
        })
        .on("error", (error: string) => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
          throw new Error("Error processing video");
        })
        .videoFilter({
          filter: "drawtext",
          options: {
            text: "hi",
            fontsize: 24,
            fontcolor: "white",
            x: "(w-text_w)/2",
            y: "(h-text_h)/2",
            box: 1,
            boxcolor: "black@0.5",
            boxborderw: 5,
            fontfile: "/Windows/fonts/calibri.ttf",
          },
        })
        .videoCodec("libx264")
        .outputFormat("mp4")
        .outputOptions(["-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov"])
        .pipe(passthroughStream, { end: true });

      const uploadToS3 = async (stream: PassThrough) => {
        const upload = new Upload({
          client: s3,
          params: {
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME!,
            Key: generateFileName(),
            Body: stream,
          },
        });
        await upload.done();
      };

      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        passthroughStream.on("end", resolve);
        passthroughStream.on("error", reject);
      });

      const createdVideo = await db.video.create({
        data: {
          name: "Test Name",
          url: singedURL.split("?")[0],
          key: singedURL,
          fileId: input.fileId,
        },
      });

      return createdVideo;
    }),

Here's the ffmpeg log.
ffmpeg started on 2024-04-11 at 20:58:56
Report written to "ffmpeg-20240411-205856.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
"C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\ffmpeg-full\\tools\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" -i ./template1.mp4 -filter:v "drawtext=text=hi:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:fontfile=/Windows/fonts/calibri.ttf" -report pipe:1
ffmpeg version 7.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-f  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument './template1.mp4'.
Reading option '-filter:v' ... matched as option 'filter' (apply specified filters to audio/video) with argument 'drawtext=text=hi:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:fontfile=/Windows/fonts/calibri.ttf'.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option 'pipe:1' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url ./template1.mp4.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: ./template1.mp4.
[AVFormatContext @ 00000262cd0888c0] Opening './template1.mp4' for reading
[file @ 00000262cd0a94c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] ISO: File Type Major Brand: isom
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Unknown dref type 0x206c7275 size 12
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Processing st: 0, edit list 0 - media time: 1024, duration: 126981
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Offset DTS by 1024 to make first pts zero.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Setting codecpar->delay to 2 for stream st: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 6965 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 6(SEI), nal_ref_idc: 0
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 7(SPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 8(PPS), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] nal_unit_type: 5(IDR), nal_ref_idc: 3
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Decoding VUI
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Format yuv420p chosen by get_format().
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] Reinit context to 1088x1920, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[h264 @ 00000262cd0bb140] no picture 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] All info found
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000262cd0888c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 82242 bytes read:82242 seeks:0 frames:1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './template1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3720 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und), 1, 1/15360: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1080x1920, 3714 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url pipe:1.
Applying option filter:v (apply specified filters to audio/video) with argument drawtext=text=hi:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:fontfile=/Windows/fonts/calibri.ttf.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: pipe:1.
[AVFormatContext @ 00000262cd0b2240] Unable to choose an output format for 'pipe:1'; use a standard extension for the filename or specify the format manually.
[out#0 @ 00000262cd0bb300] Error initializing the muxer for pipe:1: Invalid argument
Error opening output file pipe:1.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument
[AVIOContext @ 00000262cd0a9580] Statistics: 82242 bytes read, 0 seeks

I should be able to stream the processed video to my s3, but it keeps on throwing "Error: Error: Output format mp4 is not available"

Add -report to the ffmpeg command and rerun. Share link to report.

I've edited my post and include the errors logged on my terminal.

I want to see the log generated by ffmpeg, not the wrapper. I need the report output for that.

I apologize, I edited the post again and I include the ffmpeg log

The wrapper should be adding -f mp4 to the command but it is not.

It turns out the problem was my ffmpeg version, the updated ffmpeg version made some changes that results into fluent-ffmpeg struggle to read the ffmpeg formats. All I did is to downgrade my ffmpeg and it fix my problem.

For those who encounter this problem in fluent-ffmpeg, check your ffmpeg version, the new version 7.0.0 introduce some changes in its format that results into some errors. You can read the discussion in this link. Just downgrade your ffmpeg to lower versions.
